# how to enable a disabled input field when the page has completed loading - Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In vuejs, how i state an input field to not be disabled when when the page has completed loading.

i am very new to vuejs and JavaScript.

the below is a rough idea - please point me to the right direction

file:

```
<!-- chart title -->
<body>
  <div>
    <label>Chart Title:</label>
    <input :disabled=isDisabled  id="ChartTitle" name="ChartTitle" type="text" v-model="data_chartTitle"/> 
  </div>
</body>

methods: {
 isDisabled() {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete')
   return this.data_chartTitle.validated == 1;
 }  
}
```

Comment: take a look at [v-cloak](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak) if you want to hide the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, you need to replace `:disabled=isDisabled` with `:disabled="isDisabled()"`.

You can also use [a watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch). The watcher's handler will execute every time `data_chartTitle` is changed. `deep: true` means that the watcher watches every sub-property of the object.

```
<input :disabled="disabled" id="ChartTitle" name="ChartTitle" type="text" v-model="data_chartTitle"/>

data: {
    return {
        ...
        disabled: true
    }
},
watch: {
    data_chartTitle: {
        handler(val)
            this.disabled = val.validated === 1
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```

However, I see that `data_chartTitle` is used as the v-model for the input, which means it should be a string, but also as an object in your method. This will probably cause issues.

Comment: thank you soo much! much appreciated --magnus buvarp

Comment: @MagnusBuvarp, can you please explain a little why this will work? Because when the page was not fully loaded, neither `disabled: true`, right? then the input will be enabled

Comment: Vue loads the component before it populates the DOM, so the DOM is populated according to the default values of the component; thus when loaded the input will be `disabled="true"`. I don’t know why `data_chartTitle.validated == 1` should mean the input is disabled, but that’s what he had, so I just copied it. Is that what you meant?